# Aws Redis clustered session managment not working

Tags: nginx, php, amazon-web-services, cluster, redis

We are running php7 with nginx in aws ELB and handling sessions in AWS clustered redis, but session is not storing in AWS redis clustered.. Sometime it works but most time it not working.

in php.ini have changed to session.save_handler = redis and session.save_path = "tcp://redis configuration endpoint:6379"

kindly help on this.

Comment: You're going to need to give a lot more information if you want help - these intermittent problems can be tricky. Relevant configurations, logs, that sort of thing.

Answer (score 0):

Your session save handler is set to **redis**, not **rediscluster**.  See: https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis/blob/develop/cluster.markdown#session-handler

You'll want to make sure that rediscluster is a registered save handler for sessions. You can check that in `phpinfo()`.

You're also using the **redis** style for your save_path, not the **rediscluster** style.  That requires only hostname:port in the save_path, but also at least one seed at minimum.  It should look something similar to:

```
session.save_handler = rediscluster
session.save_path = seed[]=redis-config-endpoint:6379&option=value
```

Where option is any of the options defined in the cluster.markdown file (timeout, read_timeout, persistent, failover... and maybe distribute).

Failover and distributing between master and slave nodes does not appear to be documented that well (I plan to raise a Github issue) but if you've only got a few shards and single nodes on each, I believe this should work (since AWS doesn't require you to list the endpoint of each node, and just the configuration endpoint).  You don't actually need to specify any options.

You'll also want to tweak session garbage collection lifetimes and the probability that it'll happen on a given `session_start()` call to make sure old sessions are cleaned up.